# Is there a way to implement a popup menu from NSToolBarItem?

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I am trying to implement a pop-up menu (something that can be seen when in Chrome I press right mouse button when the cursor is over the left arrow).

I have a class derived from `NSToolBarItem` and I have another class derived from `NSToolBar`. In the toolbar I call `setAllowsUserCustomization`. So my right click anywhere on the toolbar brings up the customization menu for the toolbar.

Thank you for any pointer you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to subclass `NSToolbarItem`. Just give one toolbar item [its own view](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSToolbarItem/setView:) (in code or in IB). In that view, you can use a standard control like `NSPopUpButton`, or a custom view with whatever event handling logic you like.

Comment: This only works for left-button mouse events: NSToolbarView intercepts rightMouseDown events, so they're not sent down to the toolbarItem.view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your NSToolbarItem custom views to receive mouseDown events, you can follow this pattern: use a custom NSWindow subclass (or swizzle the `-[NSWindow hitTest:]` method) and forward events to your views yourself.

```
// MyWindow.h

@interface MyWindow : NSWindow

@end

@interface NSView (MyWindow)

- (BOOL)interceptsToolbarRightMouseDownEvents;

@end

// MyWindow.m

@implementation NSView (MyWindow)

- (BOOL)interceptsToolbarRightMouseDownEvents { // overload in your custom toolbar item view return YES
    return NO;
}

@end

@interface NSToolbarView : NSView /* this class is hidden in AppKit */ @end

@implementation MyWindow

- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent*)event {
    if (event.type == NSRightMouseDown) {
        NSView* frameView = [self.contentView superview];
        NSView* view = [frameView hitTest:[frameView convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:nil]];
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSToolbarView.class])
            for (NSView* subview in view.subviews) {
                NSView* view = [subview hitTest:[subview convertPoint:event.locationInWindow fromView:nil]];
                if (view.interceptsToolbarRightMouseDownEvents)
                    return [view rightMouseDown:event];
            }
    }

    [super sendEvent:event];
}

@end
```